# NameError when running script

Tags: python, oop, nameerror

While running this script I am receiving the following error.

```
  p1=Person1("Plumber",fav_food,ethnicity,name,"male") 
NameError: name 'fav_food' is not defined
```

I am new to OOP but, the way I understand it, `fav_food` is define when I defined the `Person1` class. Obviously I am wrong, but why?

```
class Person():
    def __init__(self,job,fav_food,ethnicity,name,gender):
        self.job=job
        self.fav_food=fav_food
        self.ethnicity=ethnicity
        self.name=name
        self.gender=gender

class Person1(Person):
    def __init__(self,job,fav_food,ethnicity,name,gender):
        Person.__init__(self,job,fav_food,ethnicity,name,gender)
        self.job=job
        self.fav_food="chips"
        self.ethnicity="white"
        self.name=random.shuffle(names)[0]
        self.gender=gender

p1=Person1("Plumber",fav_food,ethnicity,name,"male")
```

Comment: and where do you define `fav_food` on module level?

Comment: Sorry, unsure what you mean-i thought by defining self.fav_food in Person1 class, i wouldn't have to define it elsewhere

Comment: There are different namespaces, globals and locals. `fav_food` is only defined locally in `__init__` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove all unnecessary arguments from `Person1.__init__`:

```
class Person():
    def __init__(self, job,fav_food,ethnicity,name,gender):
        self.job=job
        self.fav_food=fav_food
        self.ethnicity=ethnicity
        self.name=name
        self.gender=gender

class Person1(Person):
    def __init__(self,job,gender):
        Person.__init__(self,job,"chips","white",random.shuffle(names)[0],gender)

p1=Person1("Plumber", "male")
```

Answer (score 0):

`fav_food` is defined locally in `__init__` and in future instance namespaces due to its sole assignment in `__init__`. It is not defined in the module namespace in which you attempt to create a `Person1` instance using `fav_food`, hence the error.

Python uses the LEGB rule for variable name resolution. It searches from L to B, starting at the level in which the name occurs. The name resolves to the first name definition found. A NameError occurs if no name definition is found.

**L** - **Local**: *first* it looks for variable definitions in the local scope of functions

**E** - **Enclosing**: *next* it looks in the scope of any enclosing functions

**G** - **Global**: *then* it looks for the variable definition at the module level. In the code `fav_food` is referenced in the module scope, so Python requires a definition of `fav_food` at the module level or higher

**B** - **Built-in**: *finally* Python looks for built-in variable definitions

In addition to LEGB name resolution, there is also object.attribute resolution. In this case `fav_food` will be defined in person instances: `person.fav_food`